# Php - how to store tuples of 3 elements in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to store three string values at each iteration of a loop, e.g.

```
$myArray = array();
foreach (..) {
  $myArray[] = // I need to store as a single row or tuple three strings
}
foreach ($myArray as $arrayTuple)
  // Do something with $arrayTuple.firstString, $arrayTuple.secondString and $arrayTuple.thirdString
```

I can't seem to understand how to do this with an associative array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you want like this

```
$myArray = array();
foreach (..) {
  $myArray[] = array("one","two","three");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should helps you, if I understand you correctly:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $myArray[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array_push()`

For example:

```
$myArray = array();
array_push($myArray, "one","two","three");
```

Or

```
$myArray = array();
array_push($myArray, "one:two:three");
```